# Edittext/Layout not resizing/going up when keyboard open

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

I placed some TextViews and EditTexts in a RelativeLayout which is in a ScrollView  via

```
Spieler1.setSingleLine();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params7 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Math.round(width/3), Math.round(height/11));
root.addView(Spieler1, params7);
Spieler1.setX(Math.round(0.48*width));
Spieler1.setY(Math.round(height / 3.5));
Spieler1.bringToFront();
Spieler1.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
Spieler1.setTextSize(height/70);
Spieler1.setNextFocusDownId(Spieler2.getId());
```

I set up Resizing in Manifest, but the Layout doesn't resize and the keyboard coveres the Edittexts.

It opens automatically the keyboard and you can enter everything until you are at the last one. You can scroll manually to the next edittext when it is open, but if you continue to write, it goes up to the top again.

it sometimes says:

```
1783-1783/com.android.inputmethod.latin W/InputMethodService: Window size has been changed. This may cause jankiness of resizing window: -1 -> -2
```

Maybe you have an idea, why this happens. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using relative layout. when softKeyboard comes up it will force layout view to pull up.

Comment: Did you read my post? It is NOT resizing as it should do... and I don‘t know why